# Equality of the products involving (prime powers - 1)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_m$ be a collection of prime powers such that $q_i = p_i^{k_i}$. I have the following questions.

1. When the products $\prod_{i=1}^m(q_i-1)^{r_i}$ and $\prod_{j=1}^m(q_j-1)^{s_j}$ (where $r_i, s_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i$ and $r_j \ne s_j$ for some $j$) are equal?
2. Is there any combinatorial problem representing the equalities of these products?

Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: $(7-1)^1 (3-1)^0 (2^2-1)^0 = (7-1)^0 (3-1)^1 (2^2-1)^1$. The primes are distinct, but the products are equal.

Comment: Thank you. simple and nice example. What if I also require $|\{i:r_i =1\}|=|\{j:s_j=1\}|$ when $p_i$ is are distinct? In this case, do we get the products are unequal?

Comment: $(2^2-1)(5-1) = (3-1)(7-1)$

Comment: $(3-1)(13-1)=(5-1)(7-1)$.

Comment: $(67-1)(97-1)=(73-1)(89-1)$, 
$(3-1)(97-1)(79-1)=(53-1)(73-1)(5-1)$, 
$(11^2-1)(71^2-1)=(19^2-1)(41^2-1)$,
$(3^2-1)(89^2-1)(71^2-1)=(23^2-1)(41^2-1)(19^2-1)$, 
$(71^2-1)(5^3-1)=(13^2-1)(61^2-1)$, 
$(41^2-1)(3^3-1)=(79^2-1)(2^3-1)$,

Comment: $(13^2-1)(79^2-1)=(41^2-1)(5^4-1)$, 
$(19^2-1)(59^2-1)=(2^4-1)(17^4-1)$, 
$(19^2-1)(3^3-1)=(2^4-1)(5^4-1)$, 
$(37^2-1)(2^5-1)=(5^3-1)(7^3-1)$,
$(31^2-1)(2^5-1)=(3^2-1)(61^2-1)$, 
$(31^2-1)(2^6-1)=(13^2-1)(19^2-1)$, 
$(7^2-1)(2^6-1)=(43-1)(73-1)$, 
$(43-1)(3^8-1)=(41-1)(83^2-1)$